# Are the Dinobots incapable of speech?

Tags: movie, transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-age-of-extinction

Optimus Prime speaks to the Dinobots in English, compelling them to join in his fight. However, the only sound we ever hear from the Dinobots is their animal roars. Are they incapable of speaking/communicating with another Transformer?

Comment: http://youtu.be/BtGdfulu5KI?t=1m50s - Me Grimlock!

Comment: Who's dumb enough to try to force Grimlock to speak English?

Comment: As @pleurocoelus alluded, maybe they just don't care to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### We don't know

So far, the AOE movie is the only canonical appearance of the Dinobots in the Bayverse movies. However, the video below (taken from [this forum](https://www.tfw2005.com/transformers-news/transformers-movie-toys-products-30/transformers-4-age-of-extinction-grimlock-toy-voice-sneak-peek-179281/)) surfaced a few months ago.

In it, a voice artist is shown to be voicing Grimlock (leader of the Dinobots) speaking in English for a yet unreleased toy. How canonical you want to take this is really up in the air, as the Bayverse toys have been known to introduce characters and concepts not in the movies themselves.

Answer (score -1):

In the cartoon *G1*, the Dinobots were created by the Autobots to be as strong as dinosaurs. ["Of course, the Dinobots have simple brains, just like real dinosaurs."](http://cybertronchronicle.freewebspace.com/cartoon-dossier/transcripts/sos_dinobots-script.html)  So, they could speak, but they spoke like cavemen.

Comment: But this question is about the film, not  the cartoon series.

Comment: Imho, the history, especially the show that *introduced* the characters, is important for the answer. Unless, of course, someone comes up with something better, whatever it may be.

Comment: The various canons are *so* disparate that while the G1 history is certainly informative, it has almost no bearing on anything else, particularly when the question is specifically about the movie. There are at least two other continuities where the Dinobots were not built, and were not only able to speak, but highly intelligent.

Comment: @phantom42 to be clear, the question makes no mention of the movie. Perhaps those who have seen the movie (i have not) think it is obvious.

Comment: It's tagged with [tag:movie] and [tag:age-of-extinction].

Comment: @phantom42 Ah, tags. I *search* by those, but i don't *look* at those. Perhaps someone should edit the question, starting it off with "In age of extinction...".